# How to make multiple Fonts in one string, python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

In Tkinter, I would like to have different fonts in one Label.
So, the practical case is this: I have a Text Widget and in the text widget there is a bunch of Labels, each containing three lines: Title, Duration - Channel, and Description.
I would like to make the Title stand out by making it bold. Can this be done? So far I didn't find information that helped me out, and in the past I encountered the issue and didn't manage to find a solution.

I would prefer not to have 3 labels, because I have nice borders around the label. It would really complicate things.

Of course, I don't mind a bit of complication if it is necesary, but if it is unnecesary, then that would be nice. It seems like it should be normal functionality, like some tags  or so.

Comment: You can have three labels for the three lines in a frame, then you can use different fonts for the labels.

Comment: Yes, that would be an option. But a more straightforward solution would be nice. Especially for cases where one might dynammicaly want to highlight words in a string. It would become a chaos of many labels.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use more than one font in a label. If you need multiple fonts you'll have to use a `Canvas` or a `Text` widget, or combine multiple labels inside a frame. Arguably, the simplest solution will be a three line text widget.